# What's wrong with C#'s enum?! It's so UGLY

Tags: c#, enums

Seriously. C#'s enum's just a plain Eyesore. (IMO).

When you parse it from a string, you get a whole line of bloated legacy looking code:

```
(EnumType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumType), value);
```

Seriously? A parse method that takes in a type parameter, and spits out an object?!
When really, it could be:

```
Enum.Parse<EnumType>(value);
```

It's a value type. So you can't use "as" instead of type cast. It's doesn't share a base type. So you can't write an extension for it either. You either resort to a static "Helper class" (woohoo.... ) or you resort to... bolting extension method on a string?! Worse than failure?.

Anyone got something elegant?

Comment: You may want to rephrase the wtf's

Comment: EnumType.Parse(value) dont work?

Comment: Is there a real question in here? You can make an extension method to convert any string into an enum with `.ToEnum<EnumType>()`. Just hides the ugliness.

Comment: Language and tone are really inappropriate.

Comment: @.ToEnum<EnumType>() "or you resort to... bolting extension method on a string?!" Been there, done that. It's a workaround not a fix. Not a bad one, but you can't constraint EnumType to an enum type.

Comment: Despite the rantish tone this is actually a pretty good question...I say keep it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.Net 4 has added a lot of ... niceness ... to Enum:

http://reedcopsey.com/2009/10/26/long-overdue-enum-goodness-in-net-4/

Comment: BTW, that's [`Mr. Copsey`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/65358/reed-copsey) to you `;-)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Weren't aware of these changes to enum.

Comment: Can you please add more detail to this answer so that it isn't just a link?

Comment: @RyanGates The magic is Enum.TryParse(). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse

Comment: @sliderhouserules I understand that that is where the magic is. I think an answer should be able to stand on it's own without the link. I don't believe this answer can. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/189763

Comment: I agree with you. The poster hadn't responded to you since you posted back in May, so I debated whether to edit his answer or just put a comment. I would have liked to have had the summary of the article myself as well -- very much so, because following the link and reading the article gave me the answer *I* was looking for. But I've had too many edits rejected by overzealous mods (plus the question is closed [again, I would say overzelous mods...]), so I just put it as a comment...

Answer (score 1):

I am coding for .net and never have a failure with `enum`. It is elegant for certain places, what you are trying to achieve *is not elegant*. Casting several `enum`s to common base? What for? Enum is sort of strongly typed constant set and should be used like this. Parsing `enum` is not that frequent task that writing `(EnumType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumType), value);` becomes annoying. If it really does go on and write:

```
static class EnumHelper
{
   public T Parse<T>(string val) { return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), val); }
}
```

Comment: He didn't actually say Failure, that was a transition from WTF and a tounge-in-cheek reference to dailywtf :) but I agree completely, if you're using Enums like this, you're possibly doing the wrong thing.

Comment: "You either resort to a static "Helper class" (woohoo.... )". And no, I'm not trying to cast to common base. I want to do exactly what you are doing, but have "enum generic constraint" on the type T. You won't know you have passed in a wrong Type T until run time.

Comment: @Sleeper Smith true. best you can is to add `where T : struct`